# Stone Scissor Paper: ReferenceError

Tags: javascript

I can't figure out why this is not working! 
I want to show the button value in the DOM!

```
<input type="button" value="Stone" onclick="userWeapon(this), getResult()">
<input type="button" value="Scissor" onclick="userWeapon(this), getResult()">
<input type="button" value="Paper" onclick="userWeapon(this), getResult()">
```

Here I used the function userWeapon(getValue). When I log this in the console, it is working. But If I want to print that value to the screen I get a reference error. Do you know why?

```js
var weapons = ['Stone', 'Scissor', 'Paper'];
var scoreUser;
var scoreEnemy;

function enemyWeapon() {
    // Get a random number from 1 - 3
    var randNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
    // get the weapon with randNumber (0-2) from the weapons array
    var enemyWeapon = weapons[randNumber];
    return enemyWeapon;
}

function userWeapon(getValue) {
    var userWeapon = getValue.value;
    console.log(userWeapon);
    return userWeapon;
}

function showEnemyWeapon() {
    var elShowEnemyWeapon = document.getElementById('enemy');
    elShowEnemyWeapon.innerHTML = enemyWeapon();
}

function showUserWeapon() {
    var elShowUserWeapon = document.getElementById('user');
    elShowUserWeapon.innerHTML = userWeapon(getValue);
}


function getResult() {
    showUserWeapon();
    showEnemyWeapon();
}
```

```css
*, *:before, *:after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

section.flex-content {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    border: 1px solid black;
    justify-content: space-around;
}

div {
    border: 1px solid red;
}

td {
    border: 1px solid red;
}

table {
    margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Stone Scissor Paper</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/stone-scissor-paper.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <section class="flex-content">
            <div id="user">1</div>
            <div id="enemy">2</div>
        </section>
        <section class="flex-content">
            <input type="button" value="Stone" onclick="userWeapon(this), getResult()">
            <input type="button" value="Scissor" onclick="userWeapon(this), getResult()">
            <input type="button" value="Paper" onclick="userWeapon(this), getResult()">
    </section>
    <section>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>You</th>
                <th>Computer</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>3</td>
                <td>1</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </section>
    </div>
    <script src=" js/stone-scissor-paper.js "></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Because you never pass anything in `elShowUserWeapon.innerHTML = userWeapon(getValue);`. What is `getValue` here do you think? Pass it too: `onclick="userWeapon(this), getResult(this)"` and use in every function.

Comment: I can't fix it... Can you post a snippet to show what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

You were calling two functions instead of calling one and passing in an argument. Here is the code you should do. I also added some optimizations to make it a little bit faster(not that that matters much). I also didn't add how to change the score because I think you can do that. If you need more help on changing the score, comment below and I will help.

```js
var weapons = ['Stone', 'Scissor', 'Paper'];
var scoreUser;
var scoreEnemy;

function enemyWeapon() {
    // Get a random number from 1 - 3
    // get the weapon with randNumber (0-2) from the weapons array
 return weapons[Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)];
}

function userWeapon(getValue) {
    return getValue;
}

function showEnemyWeapon() {
    document.getElementById('enemy').innerHTML = enemyWeapon();
}

function showUserWeapon(userChoice) {
    document.getElementById('user').innerHTML = userWeapon(userChoice);
}


function getResult(userChoice) {
    showUserWeapon(userChoice);
    showEnemyWeapon();
}
```

```css
*, *:before, *:after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

section.flex-content {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    border: 1px solid black;
    justify-content: space-around;
}

div {
    border: 1px solid red;
}

td {
    border: 1px solid red;
}

table {
    margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Stone Scissor Paper</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/stone-scissor-paper.css">
</head>

<body>
<script src="scratch_2.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <section class="flex-content">
        <div id="user">1</div>
        <div id="enemy">2</div>
    </section>
    <section class="flex-content">
        <input id="stone" type="button" value="Stone" onclick="getResult(this.value)">
        <input id="scissor" type="button" value="Scissor" onclick="getResult(this.value)">
        <input id="paper" type="button" value="Paper" onclick="getResult(this.value)">
    </section>
    <section>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>You</th>
                <th>Computer</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>3</td>
                <td>1</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </section>
</div>
<script src=" js/stone-scissor-paper.js "></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You pretty much have it, just 2 modifications to your code:

1) Add a `div` to your HTML to update the most recently clicked button.

2) Remove your inline event handlers and add them to your JavaScript.

It would look something like below:

```js
init();

function init() {
  //This is the DOM el we'll updated
  var el = document.querySelector('#display');
  //Add event listeners to your buttons
  document.querySelectorAll('input[type="button"]').forEach(btn => {
    btn.addEventListener('click', e => {
      el.innerHTML = userWeapon(e.target);
    });
  });
}

var weapons = ['Stone', 'Scissor', 'Paper'];
var scoreUser;
var scoreEnemy;

function enemyWeapon() {
  // Get a random number from 1 - 3
  var randNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
  // get the weapon with randNumber (0-2) from the weapons array
  var enemyWeapon = weapons[randNumber];
  return enemyWeapon;
}

function userWeapon(getValue) {
  var userWeapon = getValue.value;
  console.log(userWeapon);
  return userWeapon;
}

function showEnemyWeapon() {
  var elShowEnemyWeapon = document.getElementById('enemy');
  elShowEnemyWeapon.innerHTML = enemyWeapon();
}

function showUserWeapon() {
  var elShowUserWeapon = document.getElementById('user');
  elShowUserWeapon.innerHTML = userWeapon(getValue);
}


function getResult() {
  showUserWeapon();
  showEnemyWeapon();
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="Stone">
<input type="button" value="Scissor">
<input type="button" value="Paper">
<div id="display"></div>
```